# .htaccess 301 redirect issue with https Urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

we want to redirect our .com domain name to .net domain, HTTP work for us, but when user use HTTPS path, they redirect to 404 page of .com domain. Please check our code and help me, how to redirect .com domain HTTP and HTTPS both user to some other .net domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/domain\.net\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule by this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://domain.net%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Rule cannot fix a 404 if your VirtualHost is not correct. What is your 404 URL and what it the correct URL for that that 404 URL

Comment: we're using nginx, and at 404 error page, it shows " The server can not find the requested page: (port 443) "

Comment: I didn't ask for 404 content, just want to know your full URL that is showing 404. Also Nginx rules are different from Apache.